# Can I extend jQuery.ajax deferred object?

Tags: jquery

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
$.ajax({...})
  .whenValid(doSomething);
```

whenValid would basically be a function that conditionally calls another function

```
whenValid: function(action) {
  return this.done(function(data) {
    if (!data.errors) action(data);
  });
}
```

I need this to be an instance method of jQuery's deferred object that jQuery.ajax returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So jQuery.ajax returns a superset of the $.Deferred() object and not the object itself.

This will overwrite the jQuery.ajax method and modify the result returned from the original jQuery.ajax function:

```
jQuery.ajax = (function ($ajax) {
  var newAjax = function (url, settings) {
    var ajax = $ajax(url, settings);

    ajax.whenValid = function (callback) {
      return this.done(function (data) {
        if (!data.errors) callback(data);
      });
    };

    return ajax;
  };
  return newAjax;
}(jQuery.ajax));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `jQuery.ajax()` or `jQuery.Deferred` can be extended. Though appears expected result can be achieved using `.then()` where you can return a `jQuery.Deferred()` to be consumed by chained `.then()`, `.done()`, `.fail()` or `.always()` at one of the `$.ajax()` completion events or callbacks.